VBA: initializing a string array
New to VBA, and utterly frustrated. Just trying to simple initialize an array of strings.
Dim MyArray() As String
MyArray = Array("A", "B", "C")
Returns Run-time Error 13: type mismatch.
What am I missing?
Started with more complex strings, dumbed down to single letters but that obviously was not the problem.

Read about half way down the help page, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1010845)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue     Needs to be a variant array

Beginning is always frustrating but don't give up ^^
Seems you are mixing variant with array.
Using Array with a variant:
Dimenter code here MyArray As Variant
MyArray = Array("A", "B", "C")

In case of Static Array:
Dim MyArray(2) As String
MyArray(0) = "A"
MyArray(1) = "B"
MyArray(2) = "C"

Dynamic one:
Dim MyArray() As String
ReDim MyArray(2)
MyArray(0) = "A"
MyArray(1) = "B"
MyArray(2) = "C"

